# PDF/PNG export feature for Web Editor

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend, export-to-pdf

Recently my company pass me a web-based graphic editor project to handle, where the content inside the editor can be moved, rotate, resize, masking, change font ... etc

So far, i was able to handle most of the client side feature. However, i stuck on those **exporting PDF/PNG** feature which give me a lot of headache. I have been research on plugin like **JSPDF** and **HTML2Canvas** and none of this can solve my problem (e.g. HTML2Canvas doesn't support clip-path css property).

I was wondering how these popular product like [Canva](https://www.canva.com/) or [Piktochart](https://piktochart.com/)  were able to develop such amazing export feature. Therefore, i will like to seek some **advice** from developer who have experience on building web editor:

1. Is it possible to develop export feature by just using Front End technology ?
2. What knowledge is required to develop export feature. [Blob ? SVG ?]
3. Is there anything that **Back-End** side able to help regarding to this feature ?

P.S: I only have 2 year of Front End development experience and a little bit of Back End Knowledge. (Yes, i am doing this project alone.)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There are JavaScript libraries that you can use. You do not need a backend.

- [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) - You can create an HTML Canvas, for any HTML content. Then you can create an image PNG/JPG from the canvas.
- [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) - You can manually create a PDF by creating a new blank page, and start drawing on it. You also able to draw an image or a canvas on the PDF.

## More info:

- Canvas Element `toDataURL` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL
- Trigger a download from data URL - http://danml.com/download.html